# How do I create a column from the aggregate function in R using a loop without it giving me a "$" in the name?

Tags: r, loops

In R, I have a dataframe (`mydf`) that looks like:

| weight | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 0 |
| 200 | 0 | 1 |
| 250 | NA | 1 |
| 387 | 1 | 0 |

(But with 100 columns (all binary Q3, Q4 etc) and 2000 rows).

I am trying to write a loop so I can get the sum of the weights for each binary value in each column.

So for example I want an output like:

| Q1 | Q1.weight | Q2 | Q2.weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 487 | 1 | 450 |
| 0 | 200 | 0 | 487 |

I have written a loop that does this which saves the result to an empty dataframe (`empty_df`). It reads:

```
questions <- c("Q1", "Q2")
for (i in questions) {
empty_df[[paste0(i, "")]] <- aggregate(weight ~ mydf[[paste0(i, "")]], data = mydf, FUN = sum)
  }
```

This is generating the correct values but it’s giving weird column names. It’s giving me the output:

| Q1$mydf[[paste0(i, "")]] | Q1$weight | Q2$mydf[[paste0(i, "")]] | Q2$weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 487 | 1 | 450 |
| 0 | 200 | 0 | 487 |

I have tried a bunch of different things to name the columns correctly and tried using gsub to remove the `$` and the `"mydf[[paste0(i, "")]]"` but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas on how to create the output with the correct columns would be much appreciated - thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to shift to a tidyverse method, try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
mydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -weight, names_to = "Q") %>%
  summarize(weight = sum(weight), .by = c(Q, value)) %>%
  mutate(rn = match(value, sort(unique(value))), .by = Q) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_from = "Q", values_from = c("value", "weight"), names_glue = "{Q}.{.value}") %>%
  select(-rn) %>%
  select(order(colnames(.)))
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   Q1.value Q1.weight Q2.value Q2.weight
#      <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>
# 1        1       487        1       450
# 2        0       200        0       487
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pivot_to_longer then `pivot_to_wider`:

```
mydf %>%
   pivot_longer(starts_with('Q'), values_drop_na = TRUE)%>%
   mutate(id = value) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = c(weight, value),
               names_vary = 'slowest',
               names_glue = '{str_remove(str_c(name,.value,sep="."),".value")}',
               values_fn = list(weight = sum, value = unique)) %>%
   select(-id)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Q1.weight    Q1 Q2.weight    Q2
      <int> <int>     <int> <int>
1       487     1       450     1
2       200     0       487     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```r
cnms = colnames(mydf[, -1])
x = 
  lapply(cnms, 
         \(i) aggregate(mydf[, "weight"], list(mydf[, i]), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) 
cbind(x[[1]], lapply(x[-1L], \(y) y[["x"]])) |>
  setNames(c("Group", paste0(cnms, ".weight")))
```

gives

```r
  Group Q1.weight Q2.weight
1     0       200       487
2     1       487       450
```

That is your for-loop + `aggregate` approach written with `lapply()`.
To the output of the first iteration (`x[[1]]`) we add just the second column of all other iterations (`lapply(x[-1L], \(y) y[["x"]])`). Finally, we set column names with `setNames(c("Group", paste0(cnms, ".weight")))`

Data:

```r
mydf = read.table(text = "weight    Q1  Q2
 100 1  0
 200 0  1
 250 NA 1
 387 1  0", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reformulate()` to make the formula.  Then, after the aggregate, paste the question name onto the second column name.  You can then pull everything together with `bind_cols()` from `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf <- read.table(
  textConnection("weight    Q1  Q2
100 1   0
200 0   1
250 NA  1
387 1   0"), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

empty_df <- list()

questions <- c("Q1", "Q2")
for (i in questions) {
  form <- reformulate(i, response="weight")
  ag <- aggregate(form, data = mydf, FUN = sum) 
  names(ag)[2] <- paste(i, names(ag)[2], sep=".")
  empty_df[[i]] <- ag
}

bind_cols(empty_df)
#>   Q1 Q1.weight Q2 Q2.weight
#> 1  0       200  0       487
#> 2  1       487  1       450
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>